# My Script load too late

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I try to use a script for prefilter ISOTOPE from an other page, but my Isotope script doesn't load my value with the filter value. 
You can test by yourself here : http://aprime-industries.com/

Just click on "Nos Références" and click on ENTI for exemple.

[image]

You will see my dropdown list is "ENTI" selected but the filter is not active, I need to click on "Indifférent" and click again on ENTI for activate the filter and the data-filter-value.

`<option value="ENTI" data-filter-value=".ENTI">ENTI</option>`

[image]

I will give you my script for link the value from the dropdown list :

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" :  decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var preSelected = getParameterByName("filter");

    if(preSelected == "ENTI") {
        $('select[name="societe"]').val("ENTI");
    }
    else if(preSelected == "S2MI") {
        $('select[name="societe"]').val("S2MI");
    } 
    else if(preSelected == "JBM41") {
        $('select[name="societe"]').val("JBM41");
    }
});
```

And my href link :

```
<a href="plaquettes?pre=ENTI" class="hvr-bounce-out"><img src="img/entilogo.png" class="" alt="icone ENTI"></a>
<a href="plaquettes?pre=S2MI" class="hvr-bounce-out"><img src="img/s2milogo.png" class="" alt="icone S2MI"></a>
<a href="plaquettes?pre=JBM41" class="hvr-bounce-out"><img src="img/jbm41logo.png" class="" alt="icone JBM41"></a>
```

I make a jsfiddle for my isotope script [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/f0Ld07mv/2/)

---

Bump ! my deadline is tomorrow :(

Comment: I am not sure this question is on-topic as it stands: it seems to be reliant on a link to the site with the problem at hand, which means that the question will not illustrate the bug as soon as you have fixed it. However, you have made an effort to put other code and fiddles in the question, so I will not vote to put on hold on this occasion. If you can remove the link, or at least put it at the end of the question where its importance is reduced, that is best - so readers can learn from it long after the problem has been resolved.

Comment: I will make sure the question will be still understandable after, dont worry, thanks for feedback

Comment: Did you have any solution for help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is loading too late because it is inside  `$(document).ready(function(){}`. 
Window will load first and then the code inside `$(document).ready(function(){}` will be executed. 
So loose 
`$(document).ready(function(){}` 
and keep the script in header to load it before body part loads.

But it is highly recommended to keep the scripts in footer and inside 
`$(document).ready(function(){}` 
since it will load the script at the end of window load and load your html elements faster.

Comment: So, did you have a solution for make this working if i let it in the Footer ?